# android notification click not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using this code inside a service in order to get a notification if I have any new alerts but when I click on them I'm not getting to the view that I want:

```
if(newAlertCounter > 0) // alert user about new alerts
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning)
    .setContentTitle(newAlertCounter + " new flood alerts!")
    .setContentText("Tap to see where in your vecinity.");

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

    // notification click action
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ViewAlertsActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
}
```

It shows up but its not clickable, so whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

after

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

after

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

When you call `.build()` you create the notification without the `content intent`. (and no, it will not be added after because the object which will be sent to notification system will be the `Notification` not the `Builder`)

---

```
if(newAlertCounter > 0) // alert user about new alerts
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning)
    .setContentTitle(newAlertCounter + " new flood alerts!")
    .setContentText("Tap to see where in your vecinity.");

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.


    // notification click action
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ViewAlertsActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```